# Why do I get the error in extjs, "gridstore is not a constructor"?

Tags: extjs, grid, row, addition

I have a button with a handler. In this handler I call for this function:

```
onAddClick = function() {
gridStore = Ext.getStore('gridEdit');
var rec = new gridStore({
stopCode: '',
stopOrder: '',
stopId: ''
    }), edit = this.editing;

    edit.cancelEdit();
    this.store.insert(0, rec);
    edit.startEditByPosition({
        row: 0,
        column: 1
    });
};
```

When I click on the button it will give the error message: "gridStore is not a constructor".  Why is this?

Comment: I take it you're asking why you got the error message "gridStore is not a constructor"

Comment: yeah but when i had that question in there i was not allowed to post it :(

Comment: Where did you define the "gridStore" class? It certainly isn't anywhere in the Ext docs.

Comment: i thought i had to define the store?

Comment: So the question is the same: "Where did you define the "gridStore" class?"

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of errors in the code, first of all, once you use Ext.getStore, it returns an store with that id (the store is already created). So the gridStore (global variable, since you haven't use var) will point to that store.. So no need for new. 
If you want to add custom config, just use Ext.create().
The var 'rec' .. should that supposed to be a record from the store?

I don't know what you are trying to do exactly but:

-gridStore is the actual store;

-a record can be created by modelManager or by Ext.create and the model class.